# Is it normal for "modeling flash" to cause taser sounds in Nikon D80 with its built in flash?

Tags: flash, noise, popup-flash, nikon-d80, modeling-light

I turned on the modeling flash option in my Nikon D80

It makes my built in flash into a temporary flashlight when I hold down the Depth OF Field button. Both the aperture stops down and the flash is turned on at the same time (for a limited time) to preview the shot.

What freaks me out is. The flash gives faintish taser sounds when I use that option.

Comment: Not sure what "modeling flash" is, but it sounds like your flash is doing an AF assist where it will quickly flash a few times to help your camera focus.

Comment: @Robin it turns the flash to an temporary flashlight when I hold down DOF button to see composition better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modeling flash is not a continous light but a sputtering flash.  So you get a lot of high voltage discharges in a short time span.  "Faintish taser sounds" to me sounds like you are getting a pretty good deal already: usually the sound is a lot like arcing.  If you need a separate focus light, a reasonably bright and focused LED flashlight may be a good idea to carry around.  Modeling flash is more what you use in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

The sound is normal. The flash is rapidly firing at super low power so you can see what the effect of the full flash will be. I never use the feature myself.